# What axiomatic set theories say that large cardinals exist

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

The title is my question.
I'm curious since I can't seem to find any axiomatic set theory that say that large cardinals exist.
Another thing I’d like to know is that if there are any axiomatic set theories for larger cardinals like Mahlo cardinals.

Comment: I don't understand your question. "ZFC+There exists a measurable cardinal" is a set theory that proves the existence of Mahlo cardinals.

Comment: What is an axiomatic set theory for you?

Comment: I will note, though I don't have references offhand, that NFU+Infinity+Choice+Small Ordinals+Large Ordinals is, if I'm recalling correctly, in the neighborhood of ZFC+"there's an $n$-Mahlo cardinal for each $n$". (I believe the result I have in mind comes from Solovay & Holmes.)

Comment: (On further review, that NFU setup might be much stronger than the Mahlo cardinals condition I mention.)

Comment: I think for this question to be answered, you need to clarify what you mean by "axiomatic set theory." As Asaf mentioned, "ZFC+a measurable" is an axiomatic set theory proving the existence of a measurable cardinal (and a fortiori of many inaccessibles, many Mahlos, many weakly compacts, ...). It's also worth noting that set theorists routinely work in these theories, so they're not pathological answers either. Or maybe you're asking for set-theoretic axioms which aren't obviously about large cardinals but imply their existence (or at least consistency)?

Answer (score 4):

One usually takes an axiomatic set theory like $\mathrm{ZFC}$ that neither posits their existence nor denies them, and then adjoins a large cardinal axiom $\varphi$ of one's choosing, thereby obtaining $\mathrm{ZFC}+\varphi.$ However there's exceptions, such as [TG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory).

There's also some set theories that posit the existence of collections that "standard" set theories consider "too large" to be sets and consequently disallow, such as [MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory), and [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations).

Comment: I didn't know that MK, TG, and NF were large cardinal theories.

Comment: MK and NF are not. In fact, the mention of NF is rather puzzling.

Comment: MK does not posit the existence of any large cardinals. It is of higher consistency strength than ZFC, but that's not the same thing. Meanwhile the consistency strength of NF is not known (Holmes has a claimed proof that it is actually quite low - vastly weaker than ZFC - but as far as I know that hasn't been vetted yet).